# Why am I getting 415 Unsupported Media Type in Spring MVC?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm getting the below error; I tried everything but not getting a resolution:

```
HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type
```

I am trying to send JSON object to the controller as put it in the `@Requestbody`

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<a href="./getRegister">Register</a>
<a href="./delete?id=1">Delete</a>

<%
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("id", "1");
    obj.put("name", "ABC");
%>

<form action="./jsonreq" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="obj" id="obj" value="<%=obj%>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2)Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.springhibernate.bean.Employee;
import com.springhibernate.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {



    @RequestMapping(path="/jsonreq", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Employee json(@RequestBody Employee obj) 
    {
        System.out.println("JSON"+obj.toString());
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because `"json"` *isn't* a valid MIME type - you want `"application/json"`, which is also available as [`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).

Comment: @ jonrsharpe : tried but now i am getting error

 ```
HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type
 
```

Comment: So what request are you actually making? *"I am trying to send JSON"* - are you? *Is* it `application/json`? And if not, why don't you write an endpoint to handle what you're actually sending? At the very least, you should be able to narrow this down to whether the issue is on the client or the server.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe: i am sending json object in the hidden field of form to the controller... and in the controller i want the json object to map with my Employee Bean Obj

Comment: Are you? Please look in your network tab and see what you're actually sending. The short answer to why you're getting 415 is that, *as the error message tells you*, the server doesn't support the media type of the request the client is sending.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: i can see the the OBJ value is null, can you help me how to send the json obj via form to the controller?

Comment: Why don't you send it as form data? That's what forms are for.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a 415 status because your browser is sending a request with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to an controller method which only accepts `application/json`.

Ask yourself if you really need to send JSON data in this way instead of as part of the form.

If you do, one way of accomplishing it is to use Javascript to compile the data from the form (or elsewhere) as JSON and make an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) posting it to your server.

Another much less ideal way would be to remove your `consumes` constraint on the controller method, change the argument to `@RequestParam("obj") String obj` and parse the response in the controller method manually using an Autowired ObjectMapper using `objectMapper.readValue(obj, Employee.class)`.